# tensorflow cosine_similarity using sparse_placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I am using tfidf in python to vectorize two large corpus of text and then compute the cosine similarity....

.....but it is very slow.

I would like to do cosine similarity using tensorflow in an effort to speed up the cosine similarity computation. TFIDF creates numpy sparse matrices so I understand I must load these using a sparse_placeholder:

```
#tfidf_matrix and tfidf_matrix2 created from fit_transform() from sklearn's TfidfVectorizer 

a = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=tfidf_matrix.shape, name="input_placeholder_a")
b = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=tfidf_matrix2.shape, name="input_placeholder_b")
s = tf.losses.cosine_distance(tf.nn.l2_normalize(a, 0), tf.nn.l2_normalize(b, 0), dim=0)

sess=tf.Session()
cos_sim=sess.run(s,feed_dict={a:tfidf_matrix,b:tfidf_matrix2})
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("input_placeholder_a/indices:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("input_placeholder_a/values:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("input_placeholder_a/shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

when running `s = tf.losses.cosine_distance(tf.nn.l2_normalize(a, 0), tf.nn.l2_normalize(b, 0), dim=0)` i.e. the normalize function is complaining

Can I load sparse_placeholders into the normalize function?